# 3 cat() results on 3 consequtive lines

Tags: r, line, break, cat

When trying to use the below code, all 3 cat() results are on the same line without spacing. I'm trying to get them in 3 rows so I can just copy and paste them into 3 cells on an excel spreadsheet.

```
if(TRUE){

  cat(RMSE(f1,Actual24))

  length(f1)=12
  length(Actual24)=12
  cat(RMSE(f1,Actual24))

  length(f1)=6
  length(Actual24)=6
  cat(RMSE(f1,Actual24))
  }
```

Result:    5.090731.2804371.295356

Desired Result:

5.09073
1.280437
1.295356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `cat(RMSE(f1,Actual24), sep = "\n")`